# citation to literature, natbib, \cites

Tags: citing, natbib

How do we cite multiple literature pages in one place?
For example: [1; p. 2-5, 7; p. 1-3] (Pages 2-5 of Literature 1, Pages 1-3 of Literature 7) to get the citation.
It is possible to give one literature in the form (`\cite[p. 2-5]{key}`). In this [1; p.2-5] a citation will appear.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: To me, `[1, p. 2-5; 7, p. 1-3]` is is an open invitation for needless confusion. Is is that difficult to write `\cite[pp.~2--5]{key1} and \cite[pp.~1--3]{key7} ...`?